# Application won't start - how to debug?

Tags: debugging, mfc

We just released a new version of one of our applications, and are hearing early reports that it won't run on a few customer's computers.  This is a 32-bit Win32/MFC application that we have been shipping for about 5 or 6 years, so there is a history that the thing works.  The problem I have is trying to get it running on the two computers.  I can't reproduce the problem in-house, nor do I have any real access to the two computers in question.  This much I do know - the InitInstance method is never called.  I've checked it out in dependencywalker and everything looks OK (except for missing IEShims and wer.dll - but this is common, even in-house).  What other tools do I have at my disposal to diagnose this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When a program crashes during initialization, it will usually leave an entry in the windows application error log.  (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer)

There should be something along the lines to "AppCrash" or perhaps "SideBySide"